# How can I hide the cards?

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom, search

I'm creating a search function. This function looks after the matched letters in a card name and removes the card that doesn't match the letters in the search field. 
I can remove the h4 element, but I can't remove the card. 
I tried to use an ID and write style display on the ID, but that doesn't work for some reason. Can anyone help me?

https://jsfiddle.net/2xf8ktoq/

I have tried adding new ID and show/hide but getting error.

```
const cardBox = document.querySelectorAll("#cardSort");
searchField.addEventListener("keyup", function(e){
    const term = e.target.value.toLowerCase();
    const cardsName = document.getElementsByTagName("h4");
    Array.from(cardsName).forEach(function(card){
      const title = card.textContent;
        if(title.toLowerCase().indexOf(term) != -1){
            card.style.display = "block";
        } else {
            card.style.display = "none";
        }
    })
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I saw that you were searching for `h4` and just toggling the block property on h4. That was the reason why it was just hiding the title heading but not the complete card. To hide the card you need to set the `block: none` property to the card but not just heading.

Also, i see that you were setting `id='cardSort'` for all the cards. As id is a unique attribute in dom, it better you set the `name="cardSort"` instead. If your card title/name is unique, you can set it as id for each card. And then you can find all the elements by Name 'cardSort' using `document.getElementsByName('cardSort')` and check if the search key matches in `id` and toggle the display the cards accordingly.

Please check your code updated here
https://jsfiddle.net/tintin64/vk7ou5me/

Hope this helps